# Custom Fonts on Apple Mail

Tags: html, css, mailchimp, newsletter

I have a problem with the size of the rich text that automatically reduces and can not load the first font on Apple Mail Mobile 16.2, for a newsletter send by mailchimp

I integrated with the font-face as recommended by litmus / add on inline and css

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Tiempos Headline';
src: url('https://domainname.com/assets/css/fonts/TiemposHeadline-Regular.woff') format('woff'), 
url('https://domainname.com/assets/css/fonts/TiemposHeadline-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');      
font-weight: 400;      
font-style: normal;      
font-display: swap;
}
```

```
p{
margin:0;
padding:0 0 16px;
font-size 18px;
line-height: 24px;
font-family: 'Tiempos Headline','PT Serif', Baskerville, 'Time New Roman', serif;
}
```

```
<div style="font-family: 'Tiempos Headline','PT Serif', Baskerville, 'Time New Roman', serif; font-size: 18px; ligne-height: 24px;">
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Regardless of your problem and if you can fix it for Apple Mail, you should check with https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=font about @font-face, as of now this won't work on a lot of E-Mail-Clients anyways.